# Intepretation of this least square problem

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, least-squares

Given the system of equations $Ax = b,$ with $A$ being a tall matrix, what is the $P$ which minimizes $\min_x(\|Ax − Pb\|_2)$?

Comment: Are you minimizing with respect to x or P?

Comment: I guess first we minimize wrt $x$ which will give an orthogonal projection of $Pb$ onto the range space of $A$ and then to find a min $P$ for that ?

Comment: Is $P$ supposed to be a matrix or a scalar?

Comment: $A ∈ R^{m*n},P ∈ R^{m*m},x ∈ R^{n},b ∈ R^{m}$

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a convex function, you can just set the derivative to $0$ and calculate the corresponding $x$ vector. In other words, sovle for $$A^TAx = A^TPb$$